# Receiving UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type function

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am receiving an unhandled promise rejection warning while trying to promisify paypal-rest-sdk's billingPlan and billingAgreement. I need to promisify it because I need to use await in my backend but there might be something wrong with how I've coded. Please help me find what it is that I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

```
const Plan = util.promisify(paypal.billingPlan)
 const agreement = util.promisify(paypal.billingAgreement)
try{
    let billingPlan = await Plan.create(billingPlanAttributes)

   try{ 
    let response = await Plan.update(billingPlan.id, billingPlanUpdateAttributes)
    console.log('Billing plan create response:::', billingPlan)
    console.log("response from updatePlan", response)
        try{
            let billingAgreement = await agreement.create(billingAgreementAttributes)
            console.log("Create Billing Agreement Response");
            //console.log(billingAgreement);
            for (var index = 0; index < billingAgreement.links.length; index++) {
                if (billingAgreement.links[index].rel === 'approval_url') {
                    var approval_url = billingAgreement.links[index].href;
                    console.log("For approving subscription via Paypal, first redirect user to");
                    console.log(approval_url);

                    console.log("Payment token is");
                    console.log(url.parse(approval_url, true).query.token);
                    // See billing_agreements/execute.js to see example for executing agreement 
                    // after you have payment token
                }
            }
        }catch(err){
            console.log('error found in agreemtne')
            console.log(err)
        }

   }catch(err){
    console.log('error found in updatePlan')
    console.log(err)
   }

}catch(err){
    console.log('error found in createPlan')
    console.log(err)
}
}
```

The error I receive is- UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type function. Received an instance of Object at Object.promisify. Please help!

I also tried promisifying the whole paypal.billingPlan.create,  and paypal.billingPlan.update and paypal.billingAgreement.create but then I receive an error saying cannot read baseURL of this. this is supposed to be paypal.billingPlan/ paypal.billingAgreement. Not sure if this piece of info is valueable but please help

Answer (score 0):

You are apparently using a deprecated REST SDK, and deprecated billing agreements that are not compatible with the current version of the [Subscriptions API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/) (for which there is no REST SDK).

Do not use deprecated SDKs.  And, implement the current version of PayPal Subscriptions.